# Angular ng-repeat - ng-blur being called on focus

Tags: angularjs

I have a collection of people and I am creating a grid based on that collection using the ng-repeat

```
<tr class="odd gradeX" ng-repeat="person in ctrl.people" name="innerForm" ng-form>
```

two of the the data rows have input elements that have ng-blur on them

```
<td>
    <input id="firstname_{{$index}}"
           class="lower-grid-large-input"                                               
           ng-blur="ctrl.PersonBlur('FirstName', person, $event)"
           ng-model="person.FirstName"
           ng-change="ctrl.PersonChange('FirstName', person)" />
</td>
<td>
    <input id="lastname_{{$index}}"
           class="lower-grid-large-input"
           ng-blur="ctrl.PersonBlur('LastName', person, $event)"
           ng-model="person.LastName"
           ng-change="ctrl.PersonChange('LastName', person)" />
</td>
```

When I go from First name to last name - by tabbing (not that it matters) the last name blur gets called, even though I just put focus on it and I have not left that input.

So essentially I get two blur calls when I leave the first name input.  This is causing issues with disabling the tab keydown and some other issues with our implementation of sweet alerts.

#### Expected behavior

First name i change, edit or add - i tab off this input and the blur is called - some work happens behind the scenes - focus is now on the last name input.

I then do some work on the last name input - when i tab off that input its blur is called and some work is done behind the scenes on its data.

#### Current behavior

First name input some work is done - when I tab of this the blur is called - so work is done --- but the last name blur is also called - and that work is done as well. focus does move along to the last name input but that blur was called.

Comment: Can you please provide [`mcve`](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Why don't you use `PersonBlur` and `PersonChange` methods inside `ng-change`? Something like this, `ng-change="ctrl.PersonChange('LastName', person); ctrl.PersonBlur('LastName', person)"`

Comment: I cant run my blur on a change event - i dont want that function hit when there is a change of input content - need that content evaluated after they tab off.

Comment: It works fine for me [JSfiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/my14w3jq/5/)